# Geoserver WFS-T insert no response. bug?

Tags: geoserver, wfs-t

I use Geoserver + Openlayers and want to add and save some new Points via WFS-T. I created insert transaction (correct) and sent it, but no response (include errors) was returned. In console was only:

01 dec 17:34:16 INFO [geoserver.wfs] - 
Request: getServiceInfo

I tried to execute demo insert transaction but had same result.
what am I doing wrong?
Geoserver 2.5.3, Tomcat 7

Comment: Working from the browser up through the stack... 1. <strike>What is the HTTP status of the response? I don't have a WFS-T service set up at the moment, but I would expect a 201 response (resource created) or a 200 response (OK).</strike>. I almost forgot that GeoServer [happily serves up status 200 responses](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GEOS-4255) for almost everytyhing so the HTTP status probably won't be much help. 2. What do the GeoServer logs say? Can you [change the log level](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/webadmin/server/globalsettings.html) to verbose temporarily if it's

Comment: I change level to TRACE but same situation with no response. And have no response code cuz geoserver not response. I do test transaction from demo page in Geoserver. And delete transactions executed than insert tr - not. its just freeze...

Answer (score 1):

So made a workaround. I noticed that insert example

```
<wfs:Transaction service="WFS" version="1.0.0"
  xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs"
  xmlns:topp="http://www.openplans.org/topp"
  xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wfs http://schemas.opengis.net/wfs/1.0.0/WFS-transaction.xsd http://www.openplans.org/topp http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wfs/DescribeFeatureType?typename=topp:tasmania_roads">
  <wfs:Insert>
    <topp:tasmania_roads>
      <topp:the_geom>
        <gml:MultiLineString srsName="http://www.opengis.net/gml/srs/epsg.xml#4326">
          <gml:lineStringMember>
            <gml:LineString>
              <gml:coordinates decimal="." cs="," ts=" ">
494475.71056415,5433016.8189323 494982.70115662,5435041.95096618
              </gml:coordinates>
            </gml:LineString>
          </gml:lineStringMember>
        </gml:MultiLineString>
      </topp:the_geom>
      <topp:TYPE>alley</topp:TYPE>
    </topp:tasmania_roads>
  </wfs:Insert>
</wfs:Transaction>
```

have this anmespace declaration

```
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wfs http://schemas.opengis.net/wfs/1.0.0/WFS-transaction.xsd http://www.openplans.org/topp http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wfs/DescribeFeatureType?typename=topp:tasmania_roads"
```

I delete it and transaction works fine.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  I notice that you have tried to ask a supplementary question in the area reserved for direct answers to your question.  Consequently, I will delete that and recommend that you research/ask it separately as a new question.